# how to delete 0 form from os.system in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering how can I delete the 0 from `os.system` in python, for example, in this variable I can delete it without any issues:

```
user_name = check_output('whoami').strip()
output = current-user
```

but the thing is that when I run this variable :

```
from subprocess import check_output

subtests = os.system('/home/' + user_name + '/tests/cfile --list-subtests')
output = subtests 1
         subtests 2
         0
```

and if I apply the same command structure from the first command like

```
 subtests = check_output('/home/' + user_name + '/intel-graphics/intel-gpu-tools/tests/' + line + ' --list-subtests').strip()
```

it does not works, I get several python's errors, I was researching a lot, but so far I could not find a good fix for this.

Note: I'mm using python 2.7

Comment: The code you give does not work at all (eg. `current-user` as a variable or `subtests 1` and the following). Please post some code we can execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `os.system`, it starts a new process. That process' standard input and output streams are connected to your Python program ones.

I.e. when you call `os.system` whatever the child process outputs gets written to the terminal (or whereever your main program output goes). Just like this:

```
>>> result = os.system(".../cfile --list-subtests")
subtests 1
subtests 2
>>> result
0
```

The "subtests 1"/"subtests 2" lines above is just a text that had passed from the child process to the terminal. It had never been processed by Python or went to any variable. The returned value was just 0, which usually means the operation had completed successfully.

If you want to capture the output use [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote), either `check_output` (exactly like you have used in your first example!) or generic `Popen`:

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen([".../cfile", "--list-subtests"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> process_out, process_err = process.communicate()
>>> process_out
'subtests 1\nsubtests 2\n'
>>> process.returncode
0
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `subprocess.check_output()` returns a string, containing the output of the process. Hence you are able to apply string methods. `os.system()` does not return a string, but the return status, which is an integer-- and you can't `strip()` an integer.

The "output" you see is the process output, and it's dumped straight to the screen. If you want to work with it, use `check_output()`. That's what it's for.

Comment: mmm, i did not understand you, could you provide me an example please

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
commands.getstatusoutput("your command")
```

It returns a tuple. Then you can use whatever output you want